# How to specify the type of a function parameter with combined type CustomStringConvertible and RawRepresentable?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, rawrepresentable

I want a generic function that can instantiate object of a few different `enum` types I have by supplying the enum type and the `Int` raw-value. These `enum`s are also `CustomStringConvertible`.

I tried this:

```
func myFunc(type: CustomStringConvertible.Type & RawRepresentable.Type, rawValue: Int)
```

which results in 3 errors:

- Non-protocol, non-class type 'CustomStringConvertible.Type' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type
- Non-protocol, non-class type 'RawRepresentable.Type' cannot be used within a protocol-constrained type
- Protocol 'RawRepresentable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Forgetting about 'CustomStringConvertible` for now, I also tried:

```
private func myFunc<T: RawRepresentable>(rawValue: Int, skipList: [T]) {
    let thing = T.init(rawValue: rawValue)
}
```

But, although code completion suggests it, leads to an error about the `T.init(rawValue:)`:

- Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(rawValue: Int)'

How can I form a working generic function like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `T.RawValue` can be something else than `Int` with your current type constraints. You need to specify that `T.RawValue == Int` in order to pass your `rawValue: Int` input parameter to `init(rawValue:)`.

```
func myFunc<T: RawRepresentable & CustomStringConvertible>(rawValue: Int, skipList: [T]) where T.RawValue == Int {
    let thing = T.init(rawValue: rawValue)
}
```

Comment: Yes, just what I was about to suggest. This is a good example of how to confuse yourself with names; it looks like the raw representable raw value is resolved, but no, that is a different raw value. :)

Comment: Thanks, how will I now add `CustomStringConvertible` to the mix?

Comment: @matt I agree, it's confusing. No worries in my real code it has a proper/context-specific name.

Comment: @meaning-matters check my updated answer, you simply need to use the `&` operator to require the generic type to conform to several protocols.

Comment: @DávidPásztor Great. Still wondering why `func myFunc(type: CustomStringConvertible.Type & RawRepresentable.Type,` didn't work?

Comment: @meaning-matters because `RawRepresentable.Type` is the meta-type. However, you need concrete types, since you are passing in instance, not types, so you simply need `RawRepresentable`.